# How do racial favored class benefits accumulate?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

> For example,  a  human  with  paladin  as  a  favored  class  may choose to gain 1 point of energy resistance each time she gains a level; choosing this benef it twice increases this 
>   resistance bonus to 2 per level, 10 times raises it to 10 per level, and so on. -[d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/human#TOC-Favored-Class-Options)

Based on this I understand that at level 10, that paladin has 100 resistance bonus.
Is this a mistake or are favorite options very powerful and important like that?

Another example would be hp. At 10 levels, if I pick hp each level, would 10 levels mean 10 more hp per level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [an error in the text](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2lqgf?Half-Elf-APG-Favored-Class-Alternatives#36) that was corrected in later printings, including the PDF, but never mentioned as errata and so not fixed on the SRDs.  Ignore the "per level."  The new text states:

> In most cases, these benefits are gained on a level-by-level
>   basis—your character gains the specified incremental
>   benefit each time she gains a level. Unless otherwise
>   noted, these benefits always stack with themselves. For
>   example, a human with paladin as a favored class may
>   choose to gain 1 point of energy resistance each time she
>   gains a level; choosing this benefit twice increases this
>   resistance bonus to 2, 10 times raises it to 10, and so on.

So you don't have to worry about the "cumulative" thing, they're just trying to say that when you select the same bonus at different levels it stacks with itself, which really could have gone without saying, one would think.