# How do the Aasimar Favored Class Rewards work, specifically for Paladin?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin, aura, aasimar

Title says it all. I'm building an Aasimar Paladin, and the Favored Class Reward in the Advanced Race Guide says the following:

"Add +1/6 to the morale bonus on saving throws provided by the paladin’s auras"

So, is that +1 for every 6 times you take this reward, or +1 for every 6 Paladin levels you have? I can't find a specific ruling in either of the Advanced Race Guide prints, and haven't seen anything online here, or on gitp, or over on Reddit...

I'm asking cause +1/6 times you take it is a max of +3 by the time you hit level 20, and if it's +1/6 Paladin levels, and you take it for all 20 Paladin levels, that's +20/6 Paladin levels. 6, 12, and 18, +20*3 is +64 total to the Moral Bonus your auras grant allies. Which, as you can see, is broken beyond all measure, even if it's only against Fear, Charm and Compulsion.

But the +1/6 times you take it seems a bit weak. If you take it 18 times, it's only +3, for a total of +7 offered by your auras, which is nice, but there are Feats you can take to make, for instance, your Aura of Courage to give all of your allies complete immunity to Fear.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/29386/8610) that I think may reproduce perhaps the exact text you were trying to find.

Comment: You are a live saver. I'll check the 2nd print to double check it.

Comment: 2/2 effects when I get the auras. This is to help the party as a whole, since the entire point of this build (including the Feats and Spells I'm going to take/use) is to bolster the party. Yeah, I have Smite Evil to lay down the Divine Law on some fools if I need to, but I'm not min/maxing to be the big dick on campus, I'm min/maxing to be party support and tank.

Comment: I swear the whole favored class thing would've been about a million percent clearer had Paizo opted for ½-style fractions instead of 1/2-style fractions. (And watch the swearing—the site frowns on it because it has no age minimum and even little kids play RPGs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The favored class bonus applies only when you take it. Be it the extra skill point, the extra hit point or the 1/6 bonus to your paladin's aura, you only gain the benefit of your favored class you pick at each level.

> Add +1/6 to the morale bonus on saving throws provided by the paladin’s auras

The alternate favored bonus does exactly what it says it does. Everytime you take it, you gain +1/6 bonus. There is nothing about "per paladin level".

Everytime you take the alternate racial favored class bonus, you get a sixth of a point to your morale bonus. If you take it 6 times, you gain +1 to your moral bonus. If you take it 3 times, you gain +3/6 to your moral bonus which rounds down to +0. If you take it 5 times, you get +5/6 to your morale bonus, which is still rounded down to 0. If you take it 20 time, you get +20/6, which rounds down to +3 to your morale bonus (so no more that what you'd get at level 18).

Comment: I'm aware. But, if I take all 20 levels of Paladin, and take the +1/6 to auras reward all 20 times, is it +1/6 levels of Paladin I have, or +1/6 times I take it. That's where my confusion is.

Comment: OK, so it's +1/6 levels. My logic is it only adds a +3 to the auras, and since the auras only give out a +4, 4+3=7, and there are Feats you can take to make your auras do other things, like with Fearless Aura, your Aura of Courage expands to 20ft radius, and all allies inside the radius are completely immune to Fear effects.

Comment: @AustinJurgle ... Yes? I don't really get where you're going with that, but the favored class bonus only allow you to add +3 at level 18 to **the morale bonus provided on saving throws** and that's it. And that's +1/6 **times you take it** which is different from +1/6 paladin levels.

Comment: OK, final question, Nyakouai, if I take the reward more than once, say, at level 1, 2, and 3, does this stack (effectively making this +3/6)? Cause, according to how it's worded in the rules, you can choose what favored class bonus you take when you take a level in a favored class. 

Cause as written, you can take 5 favored class rewards to get skill points, 5 to get the +1/6 to the moral bonuses to saves that your auras offer, and 10 for the +1 HP. And if it stacks, then you could get the +20/6 that I was wondering about

Comment: Everytime you take the alternate racial favored class bonus, you get +1/6 to your morale bonus. If you take it 6 times, you gain +1 to your moral bonus. So it "stacks", and you have +3/6 if you take it 3 times, which rounds down to +0. If you take it 5 times, you get +5/6 to your morale bonus total, which is still rounded down to 0. If you take it 20 time, you take +20/6, which rounds down to +3 to your morale bonus (so no more that what you'd get at level 18). With what you wrote as proposition, you'd get +5 skill points, +10 HP and +0 to your morale bonus. You won't get +64, never.

Comment: Ahh. Damn. I was excited for a minute there. Oh well. Thanks for the clarification, Nyakouai. Glad to have it straight, even if it's not as broken as I thought.

Comment: @Nyakouai You should include the plain text examples in your answer. As is, reading it without the comments, it's hard to tell what the actual conclusion is. (IE you should put in "You provide +1 for your Auras' Morale bonus to Saves for every 6 times you take the Favored Class bonus, to a maximum of +3 when you've taken it 18 times" or something similar)

Comment: @Ifusaso Thanks for the proof reading. I might add a table with the exact max bonus per level later. Do not hesitate to point out if the answer is still ambiguous.